# Как расположить Div по центру при помощи margin?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Всем привет! Хочу сделать окошко по центру (очень заезжанная тема), но при помощи margin'а не получается(. Я гуглил, ничего путного не нагуглил... Помогите, пожааалуйста :)!
Вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Window In Center</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <style type="text/css">
   * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

   html {width: 100%; height: 100%;}

   body {background-color: #e6e6e6;}

   .main_window {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 auto;
   }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <div class="main_window"><p>Просто текст</p></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ход мысли в целом правильный, только `<div>` блочный элемент и по умолчанию занимает 100% ширины родителя. Для того, чтобы выровнять его по центру нужно ограничить его ширину.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.main_window {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_window">
  <p>Просто текст</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как по середине в центр? Просто `margin: auto;` работает только справа и слева. [https://a.radikal.ru/a39/1806/dd/afbccc60899d.png](Как тут :D)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно я в одном примере Вам показал два способа позиционирования

1) с помощью flexbox

2) абсолютное позиционирование

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 30vw;
  position: relative;
  background: #ccc;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  outline:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="center">center</div>
</div>
```